# Linking a library to atmel studio 6 C++ project

Tags: c++, static-libraries, atmel

Ok, I am making a CEENBot program, but that is mostly irrelevant right now. I have included the header file I need and I thought I had linked to the static library (via linker flags)  that was required to use the functions in the header file. But, apparently, I was wrong, because when I attempted to use some of those functions, the linker said they were undefined. Those functions were declared with externs, so they must come from the static library apparently, and I had not referenced to the library properly. 
I am using Atmel Studio 6, so those anybody know for sure how you link to static libaries in Atmel Studio? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If you have a 'compiler flags' (even better, 'linker flags'h setting in your IDE, you can add `-lLIBRARYNAME` to them.

Comment: I tried adding that flag using the library file name in the flag; didn't help. How do you use those flags properly, by the way?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you still have this issue, but if you want to compile C and C++ code you need to have both compilers arv32-gcc and avr32-gcccpp setup on Project/Properties/Toolchain